# Release SSH Access without raspi-config

Tags: raspbian, ssh, sd-card

I would like to know if it is possible - and if so, how would you do it - release `SSH` access without the need to connect rpi and open `raspi-config`.

I once heard something about creating a file / folder on the SD card but did not find anything on it ...

Thanks! :D

Comment: You mean you want to disable SSH server?

Comment: I want enable a SSH, but, without a command `raspi-config`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file on your SDCard called `/boot/ssh` or `/boot/ssh.txt` then reboot. When the system finds either of those files it will run sudo systemctl enable sshd for you.

You can use Windows to create those files with `echo "" > e:\ssh` it's usual to do that before you boot first time, but it works on subsequent boots.